# 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network' when exporting Keras model to TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to export a Keras model to TensorFlow.

Keras Version 2.1.4
TF Version 1.3.0
Numpy Version 1.13.3

This is the model:

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
batch_size = 32
samples_per_epoch = 1000
validation_steps = 300
nb_filters1 = 32
nb_filters2 = 64
conv1_size = 3
conv2_size = 2
pool_size = 2
classes_num = 3
lr = 0.0004

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=lr),
metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the export code:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
```

This is the error:

> INFO:tensorflow:Using the Keras model provided. INFO:tensorflow:Using
>   default config. WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model
>   directory: /home/dsxuser/.tmp/tmpbgYQQa INFO:tensorflow:Using config:
>   {'_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': None,
>   '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_task_type': 'worker',
>   '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_is_chief': True, '_cluster_spec':
>   , '_evaluation_master': '', '_save_checkpoints_steps':
>   None, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_service': None,
>   '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_master': '',
>   '_num_worker_replicas': 1, '_task_id': 0, '_log_step_count_steps':
>   100, '_model_dir': '/home/dsxuser/.tmp/tmpbgYQQa',
>   '_save_summary_steps': 100}
>
> AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 from tensorflow.python import keras
>   ----> 2 estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model)
>
> /opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.pyc
>   in model_to_estimator(keras_model, keras_model_path, custom_objects,
>   model_dir, config)
>       476 
>       477   keras_weights = keras_model.get_weights()
>   --> 478   if keras_model._is_graph_network:
>       479     # TODO(yifeif): move checkpoint initialization to scaffold.init_fn
>       480     _save_first_checkpoint(keras_model,
>
> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute
>   '_is_graph_network'

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't do `from tensorflow.python import keras` in TF version 1.3: ----> 5 from tensorflow.python import keras

ImportError: cannot import name keras

Comment: I have the same problem. I am importing keras as follows 
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()

etc. then it fails on this line: 
estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=kerasModel())

error:

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'
I am using tensorflow 1.7

Comment: Can you add your import statements too in the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need this 
`from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential` 
you should use keras api implemented in tensorflow instead of using keras api directly.

Comment: Thanks! How come this makes a difference?

Comment: I get AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

Comment: @AAI If you are using newer version tensorflow, You can just `from tensorflow  import keras` to use kears api implemented in the tensorflow. Check out this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras  for how to use kears api in the TF.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I am importing keras as follows

`from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()`

etc. then it fails on this line:

`estimator_model = keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=kerasModel())`

error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.pyc in model_to_estimator(keras_model, keras_model_path, custom_objects, model_dir, config)
    476 
    477   keras_weights = keras_model.get_weights()
--> 478   if keras_model._is_graph_network:
    479     # TODO(yifeif): move checkpoint initialization to scaffold.init_fn
    480     _save_first_checkpoint(keras_model,

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_is_graph_network'
```

I am using tensorflow 1.7

I found a solution by explicitly specifying the layers of my model:

```
def kerasModel():
    # Define the model
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    #model = Sequential()
    # input: 100x100 images with 3 channels -> (100, 100, 3) tensors.
    # this applies 32 convolution filters of size 3x3 each.
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 3), name="data2d"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='labels'))

    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

i.e. by putting keras.layers. in each of the lines as above. Previously I had relied on the imports:

```
#from keras.models import Sequential 
#from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten 
#from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

which as you can see I have now commented out. Note that I also put keras.models. in front of Sequential() which may also be necessary. See if this works for you.

Comment: your method works just because that `keras.models.Sequential` is imported from tensorflow because you have 'from tensorflow import keras` at first. To summarize, in the old codes, the `Sequential` is equal to `keras.models.Sequential`. But in the new codes,  the `Sequential` is equal to 'tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential`.